# Loading markers from outside the app in android with QCAR

Tags: android, qcar-sdk

how i can load markers at run time outside app in android using Qcar?

Answer (score 0):

I loaded the image targets in the sample project 'ImageTargets' from the sd card.
In the ImageTargets.cpp file (in jni folder) U will find the place where the app 
loads the target files (.dat file using its xml file)

```
if (!dataSetTarmac->load("Tarmac.xml", QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_APPRESOURCE))
```

I created a folder 'assests' in the sd card, copied the .dat and .xml file into it and changed the code to

```
if (!dataSetTarmac->load("mnt/sdcard/assets/Tarmac.xml", QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_ABSOLUTE))
```

You can continue with this by passing the location using JNI